# Beans in a multi-module project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm working on a multi-module SpringBoot-powered project where I have modules `core` and `web`. I use custom validators for emails, passwords and so on. The validators are defined as a part of the `core` module. I need some custom feedback messages which I store in the `message.properties` file, here is a sample definition:

```
core.model.validator.EmailValidator.email_invalid=Invalid email address
```

I also have the `ValidEmail` interface which looks the following way:

```
@Target({TYPE, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = UserEmailValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface ValidEmail {
    String message() default "{core.model.validator.EmailValidator.email_invalid}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

And obviously, I should define a bean of the `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` which should contain a local validator set up to use the local message source.

Here's what I have in my `web` module:

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
public class MvcWebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    // ...skipped...

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean getValidator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        localValidatorFactoryBean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
        return localValidatorFactoryBean;
    }

}
```

(the full version is available [here](https://github.com/melnik13/pass-pass/blob/d24eebfc48610e924308d2da4cd978ac965e2e4e/web/src/main/java/ua/tucha/passpass/web/config/MvcWebConfig.java))

It works fine.

But I'd like to move these beans' definition to the `core` module. I have the following class there:

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
public class AppConfig {
    // ...skipped...
}
```

(the full version is available [here](https://github.com/melnik13/pass-pass/blob/d24eebfc48610e924308d2da4cd978ac965e2e4e/core/src/main/java/ua/tucha/passpass/core/config/AppConfig.java))

And once I move these two beans' definition to the `core` module (to the `AppConfig` class), my validation errors stop being resolved, I get only a message label (`{core.model.validator.EmailValidator.email_invalid}`) instead of English description (`Invalid email address`).

Would anyone be so kind as to tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your kind help!

P.S. Here's the link to the full source: https://github.com/melnik13/pass-pass/tree/d24eebfc48610e924308d2da4cd978ac965e2e4e, I'll hope that it helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

In the [javadocs to `@SpringBootConfiguration` class](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringBootConfiguration.html) it is said that

> Application should only ever include one `@SpringBootConfiguration`

So first thing I would check if this core configuration is loaded at all. Probably makes sense to mark the core configuration class with `@Configuration` instead and use `@Import` or `@ComponentScan` in the web configuration class.

Comment: Thank you. I've got rid of redundant `@SpringBootConfiguration` annotations, but it hadn't helped.

Answer (score 0):

Implemented a workaround.

The bean is defined in the `core` module:

```
@Configuration
public class CoreModuleConfiguration {

    // ...

    @Bean(name="coreLocalValidatorFactoryBean")
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean getValidator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        localValidatorFactoryBean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
        return localValidatorFactoryBean;
    }

}
```

(the full version is [here](https://github.com/melnik13/pass-pass/blob/f818e77423b658ea269ee476906c2bbf607eb9f7/core/src/main/java/ua/tucha/passpass/core/config/CoreModuleConfiguration.java))

And then the same bean is mentioned in the `web` module:

```
@Configuration
public class WebModuleConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    // ...

    private final LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean;

    @Autowired
    public WebModuleConfiguration(
            // ...
            @Qualifier("coreLocalValidatorFactoryBean") LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean
    ) {
        // ...
        this.localValidatorFactoryBean = localValidatorFactoryBean;
    }

    // ...

    @Bean(name = "webLocalValidatorFactoryBean")
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean getValidator() {
        return this.localValidatorFactoryBean;
    }

}
```

(the full version is [here](https://github.com/melnik13/pass-pass/blob/f818e77423b658ea269ee476906c2bbf607eb9f7/web/src/main/java/ua/tucha/passpass/web/config/WebModuleConfiguration.java))

Well, it's a bit ugly, but it works.